# log4Net Exception with RollingFileAppender - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, log4net

I was analyzing one of our system's dump file, and I come across this exception.
The exception occurred in `log4net!log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollFile(System.String, System.String)` method.

> Exception object: 0000004ec453a8a8
>
> Exception type:   System.IO.IOException
>
> **Message:          The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used by another process.**
>
> InnerException:
>
> StackTrace (generated):
>
> ```
> SP                                  IP                                   Function
>
> 000000521608CB60 00007FFE0634E134 mscorlib_ni!System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32,System.String)+0xd4cfb4
>
> 000000521608CBB0 00007FFE05DE296E mscorlib_ni!System.IO.File.InternalMove(System.String, System.String,Boolean)+0x15e
>
> 000000521608CC20 00007FFDA9DEC700 log4net!log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollFile(System.String, System.String)+0x130
> ```

Apart from this there isn't any information in the dump, and there is just one instance of this exception.

What I understood looking at the error is that some thread was writing log to the file and at the same time, log4Net attempted to `Roll` the file, but threw the exception, that it is already in use.

Is it correct? How this can be avoided? The file is not rolled, so will attempted to roll again when new log entry comes in and if the last log entry will be lost?

We are using log4Net (RollingFileAppender) for our logging and I have checked that there is just one application using the log file.

Comment: Do you have streams in your application?

Comment: @Mafii - We are not using stream explicitly. Just log4Net configurations where appender is configured

Comment: Could it be another process holding a lock on that file?

Comment: Did you accidentially define two loggers that write into this file with log4net?

Comment: @BrunoGarcia - We have confirmed it on our server machine, there is just one process (w3wp) process using this file.

Comment: @Mafii - The file is central destination for our logs. Every class that is writing logs, has got the logger defined as - `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bar));`. And there is just one `RollingFileAppender` which is wrapped in `BufferingForwardingAppender`

Comment: @Yogi sounds quite okay, shouldn't cause any errors. Are you running this on a server or computer?

Comment: @Mafii- On production server. Isin't it possible that more than single thread attempted to log, then log4Net tried to roll the file, but one thread was already writing to file, and hence find it locked?

Comment: @Yogi The chance is little, but its possible, yea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108832/discussion-between-yogi-and-mafii).

Comment: You should [report this to the log4net developers](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#reliability) - "log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions at run-time potentially causing your application to crash. If for any reason, log4net throws an uncaught exception (except for ArgumentException and ArgumentNullException which may be thrown), please send an email to the log4net-user@logging.apache.org mailing list. Uncaught exceptions are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention."

Comment: I would also make sure things like virus scanners are excluding the logs directory.  We have sometimes seen strange issues with this.  We've seen this error also if two different applications have the same log file defined.